# I have more than two textviews but I want to copy the text of textview in andorid on user click

Tags: android

already the two textview is having a onCreateContextMenu() when they clicked for contexmenu option will appear,if user click on copy then it has to copy the selected textview text or Store in string 
I got the context menu but i need to store the text on which user is clicked for contextmenu ?

```
public class Chapter1 extends Activity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.chapter1);

        _1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        _2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        registerForContextMenu(_1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                                    ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        MenuInflater mi=getMenuInflater();
        mi.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    }        

    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id._c:
                String stringYouExtracted=_1.getText().toString();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                               "Text Copied Sucess  "+stringYouExtracted, 
                               Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            default:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                               "Under Progress", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
        }
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

I am getting always same toast i.e text copied sucess   textview2

Comment: Welcome to SO! Have you searched for how to do this yet or made an attempt? If so, please provide what you have tried or your question will be closed.

Comment: public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  switch (item.getItemId()) {
  case R.id._c:

//How to get the text of selected text among two textviews

 android.content.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.content.ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
      android.content.ClipData clip = android.content.ClipData.newPlainText("Copied Text", stringYouExtracted);
              clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);

Comment: No no no...edit your post with the code that you are trying to get to work, explain clearly what isn't working for you, and post any error messages you have, if any.

Comment: how to get the selected text from the textview
   ..tv.getText().toString()://its always taking that textview text but i need the tv1 text when i clicked on second textview

Comment: Please see my above comment. I'm not even going to attempt reading code (especially that much) in a comment. But, yes, `getText().toString()` is typically how you would get the text from a `TextView`, if that is your question.

Comment: two textview are there among them based on click i need to get the Text of that textview 
any if conditon or else

Comment: Never saw variables named _1 and _2 before. Fascinating.

Comment: Sorry, and thanks for helping -codeMagic

Comment: I will post an answer. Just a sec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save off the text of the clicked item when you get the click event

Defined a new member variable mText and inside `onCreateContextMenu`, put this:

```
mText = v.getText().toString()
```

Then inside `onContextItemSelected`, put this:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Text Copied Sucess  "+ mText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Good luck with the rest of your homework!

Comment: already i wrote _1.getText().toString() but i need some condition to check which one is clicked and that text should be stored in some string

Comment: Did you read my answer? The parameter v is the view that was clicked!

Comment: its giving the error "The method getText() is undefined for the type View"

Comment: Cast it to a TextView

Comment: thank you so much ,now i got after casting it TextView textView = (TextView) v;
  mText = textView.getText().toString();

thanks for helping me

Comment: If this helped you feel free to accept as answer.